# Имущество — находящееся или находящаяся?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать: по продаже находящегося или находящейся в собственности имущества

Answer (score 1):

Имущество - средний род, соответственно - "находяще**го**ся в собственности имущества".

Answer (score 1):

Контекст дайте, пожалуйста. У вас что-то пропущено или перепутано в смысловом отношении.

Либо "[Решение] **о** продаже находяще**го**ся в собственности [такого-то лица] имущества [признать незаконным]". 
Либо "[Сделку] (по) продаже находящейся в собственности [коровы] - имущества [гр. Имярекова] - [отменить]".
Либо еще что-то...

Comment: Объявлены аукционы по продаже находящегося в собственности Республики Татарстан имущества:
- административного здания...

Comment: Да. Тогда все правильно. "Находяще*го*ся".

Comment: Вообще где можно посмотреть правила, касающихся изменений этих слов (находящиеся,находящимися и т.д.

Comment: Да помилуйте, какие правила? 
Просто смотрите, к какому слову относится - и в каком оно падеже. Определение (прилагатетельное/причастие) стоит в том же падеже, что и определяемое.

Comment: А склоняется так:   
И. [Имущество] (какое?), находящееся (находящийся, находящееся, находящиеся)    
Р. [Имущества] (какого?), находящегося (находящегося, находящуюся, находящихся)      
Д. [Имуществу] (какому?), находящемуся (находящемуся, находящейся, находящимся)      
В. [Имущество] (какое?), находящееся (находящийся, находящаяся, находящиеся)    
Т. [Имуществом] (каким?), находящимся (находящимся, находящейся, находящимися)    
П. [об имуществе] (о каком?), находящемся (находящемся, находящийся, находящихся)